# Swift socket invalid HTTP upgrade

Tags: swift

Good day,

I've established very simple Python server (Twisted framework) on localhost:80. It works ok with telnet - i can send and recieve simple messages. But i need to connect Swift iOS app client to this server. App running on simulator.

I'm using Socket_IO_Client_Swift framework. At this moment, i've just created socket object with "localhost:80" parameter and call connect() method on start of application.

Server can see the signal from client, but client disconnect immidietly after connection with this message:

Got event: disconnect, with items: Optional((
    "Invalid HTTP upgrade"

What can i do to fix this, and what is HTTP upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem. Have you tried changing headers ?

Comment: Hi, i've found a solution. Socket_IO_Client_Swift supports HTTP-connection with server - so we need a web-server. In my case i need direct connection to socket. I've used Swift input and output streams and app works ok. I can show code if you need.

Comment: Hello thats good. Well, I am able to connect to localhost in my mac, but not when I use live endpoint ! I think for that I have to share you my server JS file. Can help in that ?

Comment: I'm afraid i can't help in this case - i'm kinda dumb in server-side programming))

Comment: The problem is solved Heroku server does not support web sockets specifically for ios